# Merge dataclasses in python

Tags: python, numpy, merge, python-dataclasses, jax

I have a dataclass like:

```
import dataclasses
import jax.numpy as jnp

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Metric:
    score1: jnp.ndarray
    score2: jnp.ndarray
    score3: jnp.ndarray
```

In my code, I create multiple instances of it, is there an easy way to merge two of them attribute per attribute?
For example if I have:

```
a = Metric(score1=jnp.array([10,10,10]), score2=jnp.array([20,20,20]), score3=jnp.array([30,30,30]))
b = Metric(score1=jnp.array([10,10,10]), score2=jnp.array([20,20,20]), score3=jnp.array([30,30,30]))
```

I'd like to merge them such as having a single Metric containing:

`score1=jnp.array([10,10,10,10,10,10]), score2=jnp.array([20,20,20,20,20,20]) and score3=jnp.array([30,30,30,30,30,30])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably just to define a method:

```py
import dataclasses
import jax.numpy as jnp


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Metric:
    score1: jnp.ndarray
    score2: jnp.ndarray
    score3: jnp.ndarray

    def concatenate(self, other):
        return Metric(
            jnp.concatenate((self.score1, other.score1)),
            jnp.concatenate((self.score2, other.score2)),
            jnp.concatenate((self.score3, other.score3)),
        )
```

and then just do `a.concatenate(b)`. You could also instead call the method `__add__`, which would make it possible just to use `a + b`. This is neater, but could potentially be confused with element-wise addition.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do so in a "jax-centric" manner by registering the class `Metric` as a [`pytree_node`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.tree_util.register_pytree_node.html#jax.tree_util.register_pytree_node). [`google/flax`](https://github.com/google/flax), a neural network library built on top of `jax`, provides the `flax.struct.dataclass` helper to do so. Once registered, you can use the `jax.tree_util` package to manipulate `Metric` instances:

```
from flax.struct import dataclass as flax_dataclass
from jax.tree_util import tree_multimap
import jax.numpy as jnp

@flax_dataclass
class Metric:
    score1: jnp.ndarray
    score2: jnp.ndarray
    score3: jnp.ndarray

a = Metric(score1=jnp.array([10,10,10]), score2=jnp.array([20,20,20]), score3=jnp.array([30,30,30]))
b = Metric(score1=jnp.array([10,10,10]), score2=jnp.array([20,20,20]), score3=jnp.array([30,30,30]))

tree_multimap(lambda x, y: jnp.concatenate([x, y]), a, b)
```

Gives:

```py
Metric(score1=DeviceArray([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10], dtype=int32), score2=DeviceArray([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20], dtype=int32), score3=DeviceArray([30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: Thanks, I know flax and I like your solution. For the moment I'll stick with standard dataclasses since I don't want to be flax dependent but I find it more elegant than defining a method.